# Create trigger in one table column value is not present into another table then don't insert it

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables

```
Employee 
Id   Name 
1    abc 
2    xyz

Employee_info
id name address
1  xyz  jpr
```

here if  I tried to insert employee info with name "**abcde**" then using trigger it will show as **abcde** not exist.

Comment: It sounds like you need a foreign key, not a trigger.

Comment: No I dont want to add foreign key,, I want to do it based on trigger. while inserting into employee_info check if name is present in employee table then insert otherwise raise an error like invalid name..

Answer (score 1):

You should use that:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER verifyExists BEFORE INSERT ON Employee 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.Name not in (
            select Employee_info.name
            From Employee_info A 
            where NEW.Name = A.name
        ) THEN 
              signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'My Error Message';

        END IF;
    END;
//
delimiter ;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html

Comment: If I want to keep that condition as name is null or empty in employee info then also dont show message only in case of value then show this message

Comment: I dont undestand what you want